# How to let users add movies to list similar to netflix?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a movie website I am working on similar to Netflix using HTML, CSS, JS and I am looking for a way to let users add a movie to their mylist, like Netflix, I have tried researching but could not find an answer. There is a working Registration and Login Form. Thanks in Advance guy!

```js
// select the strip

$("section").each(function() {

  // change the number of the "li" elements and the strip will be fine anyway
  
  var wUl = $(this).find("ul").width();
  var nLi = $(this).find("ul").children().length;
  var wElement = 100 / nLi;

  $("li").css("width", wElement + "%");
  
  // hover "li"

  $(this).find("li").hover(

    // mouse In
    function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("hover");

      var scaleFactor = 1.8;
      var wBigElement = $(this).width() * scaleFactor;
      var translation = (wBigElement - $(this).width()) / 2;
      
      var item = $(this).parent().children();

      $(this).css("transform", "scale(" + scaleFactor + ")");
      
      if ($(this).is(":nth-child(1)")) {
        item.slice(1,nLi).css("transform", "translate(" + translation * 2 + "px,  0px)");
      } 

        for (var i = 2; i <= nLi - 1; i++) {
          if ($(this).is(":nth-child(" + i + ")")) {
            item.slice(0,i-1).css("transform", "translate(-" + translation + "px,  0px)")
             .end().slice(i).css("transform", "translate(" + translation + "px,  0px)");
          } 
        }

      if ($(this).is(":nth-child(" + nLi + ")")) {
        item.slice(0,(nLi-1)).css("transform", "translate(-" + translation * 2 + "px,  0px)");
      }   

    // mouse Out
    }, function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("hover");
        $(this).css("transform", "scale(1)");
        $("li").not(this).css("transform", "translate(0px,  0px)");
    }
  );
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 0px;
}

ul, ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  color: #fff;
  background: #141414;
}

main {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 4vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 3vw 4vw;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.02);
}
.logo svg {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 10vw;
}
.logo svg path {
  fill: #E50914;
}

border {

}

section {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 8vw;
  margin-bottom: 4vw;
}
section h2 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: .8vw;
  margin-left: 4px;
}
section ul {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 98%;
  height: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;

}
section ul:hover li:not(.hover) {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
section ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
section ul li .img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  background-size: cover;
  transform-origin: top right;
}
section ul li .img:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  height: calc(100% + 20px);
  opacity: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(20, 20, 20, 0) 0%, #141414 100%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.2s;
}
section ul li .img img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
section ul li .card {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
}
section ul li .card h3 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: .7vw;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: .3vw;
}
section ul li .card .info {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: .3vw;
  font-size: 0;
}
section ul li .card .info .match {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  font-size: .5vw;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-right: .4vw;
  color: #46D369;
}
section ul li .card .info .age {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  font-size: .5vw;
  padding: 0 0.4em;
  margin-right: .4vw;
  border: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
section ul li .card .info .dur {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  font-size: .5vw;
}
section ul li .card .tags {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
section ul li .card .tags span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  font-size: .5vw;
  margin: 0 .3vw 0 0;
}
section ul li .card .tags span:after {
  content: "●";
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 0 .3vw;
  font-size: .8 xvw;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
section ul li .card .tags span:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}
section ul li:hover .img:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
section ul li:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
}
section ul li:hover .card {
  opacity: 1;
}
section ul li:first-child {
  transform-origin: 0px center;
}
section ul li:last-child {
  transform-origin: 100% center;
}

section ul li , li * {
  transition: all .5s ease .2s;
}

.container:hover .arrow-right,
.container:hover .arrow-left {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.section-frame {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  /*   border: 2px solid green; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<!-- pics by fanart.tv-->
<main>
  <div class="section-frame">
    <section>
    <h2>New Releases <i style="font-size:14px" class="fa">&#xf101;</i></h2>
    <div class="right">
<ul>
      <li class="item01">
        <div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://fanart.tv/fanart/movies/466272/moviethumb/once-upon-a-time-in-hollywood-5dfeb7beb0d22.jpg)"><img src="https://fanart.tv/fanart/movies/466272/moviebackground/untitled-manson-murders-project-5c58b437a6e65.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="card">
          <i class="fa fa-play-circle" style="font-size:.9vw"></i>
          <h3>Once upon a time in... Hollywood <i style="font-size:.9vw; padding-left: 1% ;" class="fa">&#xf087;</i>
          </h3>
          <div class="info"> 
            <div class="match">99% Match</div>
            <div class="age">TV-14</div>
            <div class="dur">2h 40min <i style="font-size:.9vw; padding-left: 120% ;" class="fa">&#xf088;</i></div>
          </div>
          <div class="tags"> <span>Comedy</span><span>Drama</span><span>Action</span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" style="font-size:.9vw; padding-left: 30% ;"></i></div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="item02">
        <div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://fanart.tv/fanart/movies/475557/moviethumb/joker-5db693c454a3e.jpg)"><img src="https://fanart.tv/fanart/movies/475557/moviebackground/joker-5d68337505352.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="card">
          <i class="fa fa-play-circle" style="font-size:.9vw"></i>
          <h3>Joker <i style="font-size:.9vw; padding-left: 73% ;" class="fa">&#xf087;</i></h3>
          <div class="info"> 
            <div class="match">95% Match</div>
            <div class="age">TV-14</div>
            <div class="dur">2h 2min <i style="font-size:.9vw; padding-left: 130% ;" class="fa">&#xf088;</i></div>
          </div>
          <div class="tags"> <span>Crime</span><span>Drama</span><span>Thriller</span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" style="font-size:.9vw; padding-left: 30% ;"></i></div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="item03">
        <div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://fanart.tv/fanart/movies/496243/moviethumb/parasite-5d2d5ab30c73d.jpg)"><img src="https://fanart.tv/fanart/movies/496243/moviebackground/parasite-5df5fb5439d1d.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="card">
          <i class="fa fa-play-circle" style="font-size:.9vw"></i>
          <h3>Parasite <i style="font-size:.9vw; padding-left: 69% ;" class="fa">&#xf087;</i></h3>
          <div class="info"> 
            <div class="match">98% Match</div>
            <div class="age">TV-14</div>
            <div class="dur">2h 12min <i style="font-size:.9vw; padding-left: 130% ;" class="fa">&#xf088;</i></div>
          </div>
          <div class="tags"> <span>Comedy</span><span>Crime</span><span>Drama</span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" style="font-size:.9vw; padding-left: 30% ;"></i></div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="item04">
        <div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://fanart.tv/fanart/movies/359724/moviethumb/ford-v-ferrari-5db74ab5a49b9.jpg)"><img src="https://fanart.tv/fanart/movies/359724/moviebackground/go-like-hell-5d0839e2ecc25.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="card">
          <i class="fa fa-play-circle" style="font-size:.9vw"></i>
          <h3>Ford v. Ferrari <i style="font-size:.9vw; padding-left: 57% ;" class="fa">&#xf087;</i></h3>
          <div class="info"> 
            <div class="match">96% Match</div>
            <div class="age">TV-PG</div>
            <div class="dur">2h 32min <i style="font-size:.9vw; padding-left: 130% ;" class="fa">&#xf088;</i></div>
          </div>
          <div class="tags"> <span>Action</span><span>Biography</span><span>Drama</span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" style="font-size:.9vw; padding-left: 30% ;"></i></div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="item05">
        <div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://fanart.tv/fanart/movies/398978/moviethumb/the-irishman-5ded4b24803d2.jpg)"><img src="https://fanart.tv/fanart/movies/398978/moviebackground/the-irishman-5de15d18d48f4.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="card">
          <i class="fa fa-play-circle" style="font-size:.9vw"></i>
          <h3>The Irishman<i style="font-size:.9vw; padding-left: 59% ;" class="fa">&#xf087;</i></h3>
          <div class="info"> 
            <div class="match">92% Match</div>
            <div class="age">TV-MA</div>
            <div class="dur">3h 29min <i style="font-size:.9vw; padding-left: 128% ;" class="fa">&#xf088;</i></div>
          </div>
          <div class="tags"> <span>Biography</span><span>Crime</span><span>Drama</span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" style="font-size:.9vw; padding-left: 30% ;"></i></div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="item06">
        <div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://fanart.tv/fanart/movies/492188/moviethumb/marriage-story-5dd0c5d3db138.jpg)"><img src="https://fanart.tv/fanart/movies/492188/moviebackground/marriage-story-5def5bf3a229b.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="card">
          <i class="fa fa-play-circle" style="font-size:.9vw"></i>
          <h3>Marriage Story<i style="font-size:.9vw; padding-left: 56% ;" class="fa">&#xf087;</i></h3>
          <div class="info"> 
            <div class="match">94% Match</div>
            <div class="age">TV-14</div>
            <div class="dur">2h 17min <i style="font-size:.9vw; padding-left: 148% ;" class="fa">&#xf088;</i></div>
          </div>
          <div class="tags"> <span>Comedy</span><span>Drama</span><span>Romance</span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" style="font-size:.9vw; padding-left: 28% ;"></i></div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </section>
</div>
</main>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This are my codes HTML, CSS, and JS , I am basically looking for a way to make the my list function work, Meaning that a logged in user can have there own separate personal list.Once again thanks in Advance.

Comment: Users will probably need to log in to your movie website so they can have their favourite movies on all their laptops, televisions, tablets and all devices. So that means you'll have to probably make an accounts system with a sign-in section, and that means you'll probably need to learn some server-side programming languages as well.

Comment: As @sven said you will need to learn a server-side language if you want to have something that working on all devices. On the other hand you can use LocalStorage for example to handle list of movies only for a user on a browser.

Comment: Thanks @sven I'll put that into consideration. Although I have a wqorking Registration and Login Form with unqiue identies no one can use to Emails to register, After Login it takes them to the Homepage and thats where the slider is

Comment: Actually I have small question for you @Vivflix how did you do login form without server side programming language and registrations as well

Comment: I didn't say I wasn't using a server @Nurbek Boymurodov, I am using a localhost server XAMPP, to maintain the website before i Publish it, I am just looking for a way to make the favourites button work

Comment: Please add `jquery` to the question's tags.
Thank you.